# Do most vampires have powers?

Tags: magic, vampire, powers, twilight

In the *Twilight* universe, some vampires gain no powers when they turn (you know, except for diamond-hard skin, strength enough to lift a car, regeneration, and being able to run at 100 miles per hour).

On the other hand, some gain additional powers.
Edward can read minds. Alice can see the future. Chelsea can manipulate people's emotional bonds.

This is because the nature of vampification is to enhance the qualities that someone already has. Those humans with latent powers get full-fledged powers when they turn, whereas humans without such powers simply gain enhanced personality traits.

How common are vampires with special powers? Clearly most of Carlisle's coven has such abilities, as do many of the Volturi, but is this the norm, or are powers more rare among vampirekind as a whole?

Comment: Maybe the writer got confused between vampires and X-men. Anyways +1, as it's a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

Our best estimate of how common vampire powers are comes from *Eclipse*. In this book, Victoria, an enemy of the Cullen coven, creates an army of newborn vampires to take on the Cullens and werewolves. The vampires present elsewhere in the book are simply too skewed to provide an accurate representation of frequency. Carlisle seems to have an affinity for vampires with powers, for example, and specifically gathers some near the end of *Breaking Dawn*.

The army of newborns had about 22 members at the end:

> “You’ve done so well,” our creator cooed, and there was another kiss.
> “Twenty-two!”
>
> “Is it time?” Riley asked eagerly.
>
> Her answer came back fast, like a slap. “No! I haven’t decided when.”
>
> “I don’t understand.”
>
> “You don’t need to. It’s enough for you to know that our enemies have
> great powers. We cannot be too careful.” Her voice softened, turned
> sugary again. “But all twenty-two still alive. Even with what they are
> capable of… what good will it be against twenty-two?” She let out a
> tinkling little laugh.
>
> —*The Short Second Life of Bree Tanner*

**Of those vampires, only two, Raoul and Fred, had special abilities. So our best estimate of the percentage of vampires with special abilities is about 9%.**

Of course, the percentage of vampires with special powers seen in the plot is significantly higher, for the reasons previously mentioned.

Comment: @anaranjada - There's some evidence that they can be under rather special circumstances. I.e. proper reproduction, not turning.

Comment: @anaranjada - Specifically, Renesme's power is clearly related to her mother's and father's. Bella blocks, Edward receives, Renesme throws. It's like football.